# Select query on kdb+ TSDB table with nested dictionary

Tags: database, dictionary, tags, time-series, kdb

For storing time-based data grouped by tags in a kdb+ TSDB I have created a table with the columns `timestamp`, `val` and `tags`. Tags are key-value pairs, so I used a dictionary for storing such information in the column `tags`.

Query for creating the table:

```
myTable:([]timestamp:-12h$();val:-9h$();tags:());
```

Query for inserting some example data:

```
`myTable insert ("P"$"2015-11-30 13:10:45.126381"; 521.45117; `house`room!215 111)
```

How can I get all data/rows of house 215? I tried the following query with no success (type error):

```
select from myTable where tags[`house]=215
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access the elements in the dictionary, you will need to index at depth - need to deal with 2 levels of nesting in this case. The outer index is the row count, inner index is dictionary key.

In q, to index at depth ([elide](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#310-elided-indices)), you omit one of the index levels, in this particular case, the query will be:

```
q) select from myTable where tags[;`house]=215
    timestamp                     val      tags
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    2015.11.30D13:10:45.126381000 521.4512 `house`room!215 111
```

A cautionary note: if the `tags` dictionaries in each row aren't homogeneous (same keys + same types for values), you may get a `'type` error thrown for rows where the `tags` dictionary is missing the `house` key, as Kdb+ will return a null value which may not be of the expected type. As a result, may need to use the match operator ([~](http://code.kx.com/nwiki/Reference/Tilde)).

Eg:

```
q) select from myTable where tags[;`house]~\:215
    timestamp                     val      tags
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    2015.11.30D13:10:45.126381000 521.4512 `house`room!215 111
```

Note, have used the each-left ([`\:`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-left))adverb here. See [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-left) for more details on adverbs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Some of the data/rows have no tags. Thus, is it possible to create an empty dictionary in the table column, so I can still use your first solution (without the match operator)?

Comment: You could add a sentinel value into each row with all expected keys with values set to nulls of the appropriate type, however this will increase memory and disk space usage unnecessarily. Moreover, may not be appropriate if nulls values have meaning in tge data. If you dont want ro use the match operator, to handle the case where rows may not have tags, you can add an additional clause in the `select`, prior to the dictionary check which checks the type of the value, to ensure it is a dictionary / or in case of using empty dictionary ensure there is at least 1 entry in the dictionary.